# How to Create a Comprehensive Calendar for a Master Project Workplan that Includes Timelines from all 9 of Other Projects

Tags: ms-project

So I have 9 projects that are working concurrently.  Many of the resources used are the same. We have different work-plans for each, but we want to put it into one master-plan.  I have created the master plan, but I need a calendar that shows all of the tasks and work-plans for all of the projects in one calendar.  How do I do that?

Comment: Not an answer but "many of the resources used are the same" signals that there's quite a tricky time/priority management issue at your company/division.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a master project by inserting the project plans together.  I am guessing you have not created a resource pool file nor are you working on Project server.  If the same resources work on the nine project plans, best to create a resource pool file and attach the resources to each plan.
see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-share-a-resource-pool-64a2416e-b811-4ddf-b039-e0347e233581